# Angularjs Compile sass

Tags: angularjs, npm, sass

I've searched and tried a lot but I can't get sass working with the default compiler in Angular 2.

I've imported [bulma](http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/) framework(sass) like this: `npm install bulma`. Then in `styles.css` that comes with a fresh install of Angular 2:

```
@import "bulma";
```

But I receive lots of errors:

```
styles.css:3Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "-!./../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?sourcemap!./bulma"(…)
```

How do I get this to work!!!??!?

Comment: angular2 compiler has nothing to do with sass. Are you using angular-cli or something else that compile your sass in your project ?

Comment: Yes I use ```angular-cli```

Comment: Then angular-cli compiles your sass into css for you. You don't have anything to worry about ;)

Comment: Do you use `ng serve` to start the project ?

Comment: Yes I use ```ng serve```. So how could I get ```bulma``` to work?

Comment: Which angular-ci version are you running ? `ng --version`

Comment: ```angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.20-4
node: 6.2.2
os: darwin x64```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `Bulma` with angular cli, here's what you should do :

```
npm install --save bulma
```

And in your `src/styles.scss` just import it :

```
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```